# Grails application does not appear in the Netbeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: grails, netbeans-8

I use NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 to create Grails application.But when I created Grails application, it didn't appear in the Projects tab.I use Grails version(3.0.8).I tried a lot but I don't know where is wrong.

Comment: I am very sure I read somewhere that grails 3.x does not work with NetBeans 8.02. You need to upgrade to NetBeans 8.1< instead. Of course, ensure you grails and groovy paths are configured correctly

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 8.0.2 does not support Grails 3.x.  I recommend you upgrade Netbeans to 8.1 or use an older version of Grails, ej. 2.7